# git status lists all the files on my pc

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to use git and GitHub.

I think I have set it up successfully (meaning that it is working).

However when I use the git status command I seem to get back all the files on my PC as untracked files (see the attached pic). I'm worried that if i use the commit command that all these files will be added to the repository in GitHub. I'm not quite sure what to do here, please could you advise me or point me in the right direction.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: What’s the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`?

Comment: Looks like you've created a repo for your entire disk.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have created a repo for too many folders. Make sure you create a new repo (`git init`, `git clone`) only in your project folder.

For example, you create a new folder on your Desktop:

`C:\Users\User1\Desktop\project`

You go into the folder:

`$ cd C:\Users\User1\Desktop\project`

Then you create a new local git repo:

`$ git init`

Now everything in this folder will by tracked by git (unless you use .gitignore).

Comment: Yip - that's exactly what I did. It's all sorted out now. (Does the original repo with all the folders still exist? if so How can I cancell it - or does it not really matter?. Thank you for helping me out, and teaching me something new.

Comment: The bad repo is in `C:\Users\back105`, delete the `.git` directory there to get rid of it.

Comment: Just like @gronostaj said, all you need to do in order to delete a local repo is to delete `.git` folder.

Answer (score 0):

use `rm -fr .git` to delete all the `.git` files and after go to your file
and type `git init`